# Understanding sudoers:

Tags: shell, sudo, chmod

I have a Unix script which creates a temporary log file, say `tempfl.log`.
When this file is created it has permission `rw-r--r--`.

There is a line

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers tempfl.log 2>&1
```

But when the script is done the permission changes to `r--r--r--` but it should be `rw-r--r--`. If I change the line to

```
chmod 0644 /etc/sudoers tempfl.log
```

The permissions are right for `tempfl.log` but it throws errors saying:

> sudo: /usr/local/etc/sudoers is mode 0644, should be 0440

I do not understand what sudoers is doing and what is wrong.

Comment: thanks for the responses. 
what i understand is that, the command 
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers tempfl.log 2>&1 is changing the file permisssion for both sudoers and templ.log to 440
but what i want is that the file templ.log should have the permission 644.
is my understanding right ?
so the solution to my problem is
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers tempfl.log 2>&1
chmod 644 tempfl.log
Please let me know if these 2 commands are going to create any error.

Comment: I would just remove the /etc/sudoers from the command, you shouldn't ever have to change the permission of that file.  If for some reason you needed to modify it, then you would just have two chmod commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is changing the permission of 2 files, /etc/sudoers and tempfl.log.  Split the command in two lines and you should be fine.

Comment: please have a look at the comment i added.

Answer (score 5):

Your script is doing *exactly* what you're telling it to do:

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers tempfl.log
```

will apply `r--r-----` to both of those files.

You really shouldn't be fiddling around with the `sudoers` file unless you're writing admin scripts and, even then, the permissions should be left alone since that helps secure your system. The `sudo` program itself checks the permissions of its configuration file and warns you (as you've seen). Listen to it. It obviously knows better than you :-)

Are you sure you aren't just trying to run certain parts of your script under `sudo`, as in:

```
sudo chmod 0440 tempfl.log 2>&1
```

If not, and you really want to modify both files (but with different permissions, use two separate commands:

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers 2>&1
chmod 0644 tempfl.log 2>&1
```

Comment: ya, im sure of it.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers tempfl.log` it changes the permissions of `/etc/sudoers` and `tempfl.log` to both be 0440, which is wrong.

When you write `chmod 0644 /etc/sudoers tempfl.log` it changes the permissions of `/etc/sudoers` and `tempfl.log` to both be 0644, which is wrong.

Do you need to change permissions on `/etc/sudoers` at all? Did you actually want to write `chmod 0644 tempfl.log`?

Comment: Agree, there is not a practical need I can think of to change the permissions of `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Nothing should touch `/etc/sudoers` at all besides `visudo`.